# can I force an animation in android to take something else than float?

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to move a view inside a layer, something like an Horizontal Scroll, I have done it with motion events and I need to add an animation. The view should follow the finger on the screen all the time and when it's released it should, from that position move to the edge of the screen. Now I managed to do all of this but I have problems with the animation coordinates since it takes on only float values and I need it to take 2 digit values after the 0.

Here is my animation attempt:

```
public static Animation inFromRightAnimation() {
    Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, temp/1000,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
    inFromRight.setDuration(500);
    return inFromRight;
}
```

temp should be the value where the finger is and it's usually something between 100-300, so I divide it by 1000 to get 0.36 lets say but because the animation will accept temp only as float I get only 0.3. Any ideas how I can make it to get 0.36?

Answer (score 1):

Try `(float)temp/1000.0` instead.